# Zend File Upload and Element Decorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-file

I have the problem, that the following Zend Form throws an error.
The problem is the "file"-element and using setElementDecorators.

```
    class Products_AddForm extends Zend_Form
{
    function init() {

       // other form elements...

       $uploadElement = new Zend_Form_Element_File('Excel');
       $uploadElement->setLabel('Excel');
       $this->addElement($uploadElement);

       $this->setElementDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper', 
            'Errors',
            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
            array('Label', array('tag' => 'th')),
            array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
        ));



    }
}
```

This throws an error.

```
(Warning: Exception caught by form: No file decorator found... unable to render file element Stack Trace: #0 )
```

Adding `$uploadElement->addDecorator('File');` at the end after the `SetElementDecorators` will work, but this will give me the file element twice!

Can anybody help, please?

TIA
Matt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The File element requires it's own decorator - Zend_Form_Decorator_File.

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
      'File',
      'Errors',
      array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
      array('Label', array('tag' => 'th')),
      array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
));
```

[edit]

Have just noticed that you are also using other form elements.

After your original code, add:

```
$this->getElement('Excel')->setDecorators(
    array(
        'File',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'th')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr'))
    )
);
```

That way, ViewHelper is added to all other elements, and for your File element File is used instead.

Comment: Thanks 4 ur help. Adding this throws: Warning: Exception caught by form: Method getMaxFileSize does not exist Stack Trace: #0

Comment: that works. havnt noticed this in the docs of zend!? :/ THANKS!