# ZF1: Why does Zend_Element_File return an error when no file is posted, even when it is not required?

Tags: php, zend-framework

It only happens in the CLI when I'm doing a unit test.  I know it has to do with the FILES super global not getting populated since i'm not actually submitting the form, but why is the form being marked as erroneous and with no error messages?

Comment: Is there in fact an error but you simply don't see it because the element lacks that decorator?

Comment: Found a similar post that shows what I mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580839/zend-file-upload-and-element-decorators

Comment: Hmm suppose if this is a unit test, you are in fact checking the form's error collection, and my comments are not applicable.  Suppose quick fix drop in a isValid() of your own, which in turn calls parent's, set something generic if error message is empty.  Maybe an [old bug](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/File-element-empty-error-messages-td663512.html)?